# Line always hittable

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, line, ellipse

**So far I got no answer, If someone knows how to fix this .. Please let me know. Thanks**

I have the following situation:

I draw two Ellipse with an red X on the center on my UI.

I'm using the center Ellipse to drag them wherever I want on my screem. It works really well and if I don't click on the red X, I can see the Ellipses being re-drawn with every mouse movement.

The problem I'm having is this:

Every time I click on the red X, I stop seeing the Ellipses re-drawing. But once the LeftButton is up the Ellipses go to the right place.

Has anyone any idea of what might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

**[Edit1]**

```
    private void canvasArea_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) && flag_centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown)
        {
            flag_UpdateEllipseCenter = true;
            UpdateEllipseCenter();
            DrawingEllipse();
        }
        else
            flag_UpdateEllipseCenter = false;
    }
```

I'm sure that both conditions are met.

**[Edit2]**

```
    private void centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        flag_centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown = true;
    }
```

Making sure that that variable is true.

**[Edit3]**

To help clarifying my problem: http://s14.postimg.org/6sajsb5tp/ellipse.png

**[Edit4]**

The xml code:

```
    <Canvas Background="Transparent" Name="canvasArea" MouseLeftButtonDown="canvasArea_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="canvasArea_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="canvasArea_MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="612" Canvas.Top="577" Height="23" Name="tBCreationTime" Text="TextBlock" />
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="447" Canvas.Top="577" Height="23" Name="tBCoordinates" Text="TextBlock" Width="160" />
        <Ellipse Name="externalEllipse" Height="0" Width="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="externalEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="externalEllipse_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        <Ellipse Name="centerEllipse" Height="0" Width="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        <Line Name="targetHorizontal"></Line>
        <Line Name="targetVertical"></Line>
    </Canvas>
```

Updating the Ellipse center:

```
    private void UpdateEllipseCenter()
    {
        Point newEllipseCenter = Mouse.GetPosition(canvasArea);

        ellipseCenter = newEllipseCenter;
    }
```

Drawing the Ellipses and Lines:

```
    private void DrawingEllipse()
    {
        bool addRmvObjcts = true;

        if (mousePositionDown.X != mousePositionUp.X && mousePositionDown.Y != mousePositionUp.Y)
        {
            addRmvObjcts = AddRemoveCanvasObjects(addRmvObjcts);

            if (flag_UpdateEllipseSize || flag_UpdateEllipseCenter)
            {
                externalEllipse.Height = externalEllipse.Width = drawHypotenuse;
            }
            else
            {
                double diffX = mousePositionUp.X - mousePositionDown.X;
                double diffY = mousePositionUp.Y - mousePositionDown.Y;

                drawHypotenuse = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((diffX), 2) + Math.Pow((diffY), 2));
                externalEllipse.Height = externalEllipse.Width = drawHypotenuse;

                ellipseCenter.X = ((mousePositionDown.X + ((mousePositionUp.X - mousePositionDown.X) / 2)));
                ellipseCenter.Y = ((mousePositionDown.Y + ((mousePositionUp.Y - mousePositionDown.Y) / 2)));
            }

            AddRemoveCanvasObjects(addRmvObjcts);
            SettingObjectsPosition();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What type of control is the red X and what happens if you set its `IsHitTestVisible` property to `false`? It might be easier to help if you post the code you have at the moment.

Comment: Hi, I have `IsEnabled` `Focusable` and `IsHitTestVisible` setted as false, but even so it's not working. Red X is made with two wpf lines <Line></Line>

Comment: Can you confirm that `flag_centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown` is set to `true` when you click on the red X?

Comment: Yes, it's set true. Every time the mouse is inside the center Ellipse where red X is drawn, the `flag_centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown` is setted to true.

Comment: @keyboardP any idea of whay might be happening?

Comment: @Probst : try adding e.MouseDevice.Capture(canvasArea) to the centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown method. And is that all your methods about mouse events with these elements, or do you have also a method for like, MouseUp event ?

Comment: @MichaëlPolla , thank you for helping. I'll try your method and soon as I get some results I'll report back to you. Yes those are all event I use to re-draw the Ellipse. I have a few other but none of them make use of flag_centerEllipse_MouseLeftButtonDown, and I'm sure that this variable is always true when it's needed and false when it's not.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla my problem persists, even with your recommendation =\

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to edit your question and add your XAML (at least the UI part), and the UpdateEllipseCenter and DrawingEllipse methods ?

Also, for testing, try to add a MouseLeftButtonDown event property to your redX, exactly the same as you wrote for centerEllipse.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla I already tried to add the MouseLeftButtonDown to my redX, It didn't work =\

Comment: @MichaëlPolla nothing? =\

Comment: Nope, sorry :-/ can't find any new idea... What I would try maybe is to add another object to the center ellipse (like a small rectangle) and see how it behaves (if it has the same problem as the redX). Also, try to had "e.handled = true;" in canvasArea_MouseMove.

Comment: @MichaëlPolla Okay, thanks anyway :) I'll try these last hints and if I get any good answer I'll let you know. Hug.